# Nagios Network Analyzer installation error on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, nagios, analyzer

I am having trouble trying to install nagios network analyzer on Ubuntu. I have successfully downloaded and compiled but cannot install.

The step entails entering `./fullinstall` but when I do so, it says

```
Installation step failed - exiting.
Check for error messages in the install log (install.log).

If you require assistance in resolving the issue, please include install.log
in your communications with Nagios Enterprises technical support.

The step that failed was: 'prereqs'
```

I have tried to install `yum` but when I do that it says

```
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

If you have any advice, or know what is wrong, I would greatly appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually Ubuntu isn't a supported OS for Network Analyzer, you'll want to install it on top of CentOS or RHEL 6/7.

Just wanted to post this in case anyone else had a similar question.